# Canvas not drawing correctly (unstable)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm building an HTML5/javascript "simple" game, but I'm having an unusual problem with my canvas drawings. It is unstable.

I have a map, that needs to be drawed that way:

[image]

The background have 2 layers: the ocean, and the islands.
The UI have 6 or more buttons/images.

Sometimes it draws like this:

[image]

And sometimes doesnt even draw the UI:

But after a few wrong drawings (F5's), it starts to draw everthing correctly.
So, it is quite unstable and im not getting why.
Here is my code for these drawings:

```
// Background Layers
    Game.m_gameUI.drawBG();

    // Draw User Interface
    Game.m_gameUI.drawUI();     

    // Draw Score
    Game.m_gameUI.drawScore();

drawBG : function () {  

    // Layer 1
    var img1 = new Image();

    img1.id = 'map2_bg';
    img1.src = GameUI.BKGIMG3_SRC;

    GameUI.m_canvasDraw.drawImage( img1, 0,0, GameUI.actualCanvasWidth, GameUI.actualCanvasHeight );

    // Layer 2
    var img2 = new Image();

    img2.id = 'map_bg';
    img2.src = GameUI.GAME_MAP_SRC;

    GameUI.m_canvasDraw.drawImage( img2, 0,0, GameUI.actualCanvasWidth, GameUI.actualCanvasHeight );
},


drawUI : function () {  

    GameUI.m_canvasDraw.globalAlpha = 1;

    // BagPack
    GameUI.drawUiImage( 'mochila' , GameUI.actualCanvasWidth - 59, 110 , 59, 66 );

    // Home
    GameUI.drawUiImage( 'home' , GameUI.actualCanvasWidth - 102, 0 , 102, 58 );
    //GameUI.setUiEvent( 'home' );

    // Points
    GameUI.drawUiImage( 'bandeira' , 0, 0 , 164, 34 );

    // Help
    GameUI.drawUiImage( 'ajuda' , 0, GameUI.actualCanvasHeight - 71 , 84, 71 );

    // Email
    GameUI.drawUiImage( 'email' , GameUI.actualCanvasWidth - 102 - 96, 0 , 131, 58 );

    // Volume
    GameUI.drawUiImage( 'volume' , GameUI.actualCanvasWidth - 66, GameUI.actualCanvasHeight - 71 , 66, 71 );
},

drawUiImage : function ( image, x, y, width, height ) {

    GameUI.m_canvasDraw.restore();

    var img = new Image();

    var filename_off = image + '_off.png';
    var filename_on = image + '_on.png';

    img.id = image;

    // Assuming you instantiated the image url on class atributes
    img.src = GameUI.ui_img_folder + filename_off;

    // Add the variable into class
    GameUI[image] = image;

    // Draw it
    GameUI.m_canvasDraw.drawImage( img, x, y, width, height );  
    GameUI.m_canvasDraw.restore();
},
```

Am i blind or something?
Or just drawing on wrong order?

Any tip will be apreciated.
Thanks,
Victor Souto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading (Creating) an Image is an asynchronous operation. In your code you are doing something like this (pseudo code):

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://example.com/myImage.png";
canvas.drawImage(img, ...);
```

If you have a fast connection (local LAN, ...) or the image is cached then maybe your image after "img.src=..." is ready to use for drawing.

After pressing F5 several times, I guess your images is in the cache so it seams to work.

To solve your problem, you have to wait for the loaded event.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { /* insert draw code here */ }
img.src = "http://example.com/myImage.png";
```

For a game development, I recommend to build or use a asset library, that deals with loading/caching of image resources.

By the way, turn off browser caching (e.g.: chrome -> dev tools -> settings) during development to avoid caching issues.

Comment: You couldn't be more right. 
It fixed my problems.

I put all my drawings "onload" functions and started to respect the drawing orders.
The problem was that it was drawing everything, but the map layers were being placed on top of the UI elements.

Thank you.